# How to keep the variable value in memory?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

Each user has to login to access to my app. Afterwards, I need to use the user's login to make several `RestSharp` requetes. How can I keep this login until the app quits? I thought to save it in `AppResources.resx` file but I don't know how to set the value in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in the IsolatedStorage

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Comment: The link is no longer working

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution - to save data in [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)